# Data From MULTIPLE Fact Tables in ONE Report (one Table)

Tags: business-objects

If every fact table in BusinessObjects has to have one assigned context (1 context per 1 fact table), then it shouldn't be possible to show the data (measures) from TWO fact tables in ONE REPORT (ie. in ONE TABLE). Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can select objects from different contexts in the same data provider, if you have the option *Multiple SQL Statements for each context* enabled (located in the SQL Options of the Data Foundation). In that case, it will generate a separate SQL query for each context and combine them in the microcube.

Another option is to create two different data providers within the same document and merge the common dimensions (it may do this automatically if you have auto-merging turned on). Thus, you'll be able to combine the two measures in a table with the merged dimensions from both fact tables.

I wouldn't state that every fact table *has* to have a context as a hard rule. I only use contexts when I need to: e.g. to prevent a loop or to solve a chasm trap. Other than that, there is no hard rule that requires the use of contexts. Just like aliases, they're techniques/features to help you define you data model and to overcome data modelling issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, use measures from multiple fact tables in the same block, and this is one of the strengths of Business Objects.  If the two contexts share common dimensions, you can analyze the measures along the same axes.  The fact that two contexts and two SQL statements are used to retrieve the information is completely transparent to the end user.